# Jest encountered an unexpected token UI-Kitten

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, expo, react-native-ui-kitten

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file that Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

      1 | import React from 'react'
    > 2 | import { Button, Layout, Icon } from '@ui-kitten/components'
        | ^
```

I've added this to my Jest config and seen no change, my app should use babel by default as it was made by expo which installed.

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/(?!@ui-kitten/components)"
    ]
},
```

Comment: you need to extend the list of transformIgnorePatterns as described in https://docs.expo.io/versions/latet/guides/testing-with-jest/ :)

Comment: It appears you solution did work for that issue so thank you, but I am getting a new one, for where my app is registering its entry point.

If you add your answer in the submission area I will solve this question

Comment: TypeError: (0 , _expo.registerRootComponent) is not a function

Comment: you can try posting a reproducible example to https://forums.expo.io

Comment: sorry, broken link, here is the correct one https://docs.expo.io/guides/testing-with-jest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to extend the list of transformIgnorePatterns as described in docs.expo.io/versions/latet/guides/testing-with-jest :) – brentvatne Feb 14 at 1:35